# How to correctly pass/add Strings from HashSet<String> in another, HashSet<String>?

Tags: java, string, hashset

I have the following problem:

I am parsing a column from a voluminous tab separated values files ("original file") in a hashSet depending on various parameters. 
I want to parse it once, and write it as a simplified file ("parsing result") where I will not need to re split/filter everything everytimes, but just have to read the "parsing result" file then built a second hashSet retrievedHS, as long as I launch the program with the right parameter.

When I checked that result where the same, I had a strange behavior.
when I read things in a third file (phonebook) and try to check the content of the lines of this file for containing a name I know to be present in the original file and thus in originalHS,  (originalHS.contains(knownName) is true, but retrievedHS.contains(knownName) is false while it is technically the same.

I tried again to make this question as clear and the code as simplified as I could,

Thanks for any help

---

```
    HashSet<String> originalHS =originalParser(Original.txt)
    //method that parse a voluminous original.txt file (a tsv file) retrieving the first column based upon //other criterias from the other columns.

    System.out.println ("Debug: Display name collection: "+originalHS.toString());
                    //Debug: Display name collection: [Smith, Johnson, Bates]

    String name="Smith";

    if(originalHS.contains(name)){ System.out.print("true")
      else { System.out.print("false");

    //test for presence of name from a third file in this set
    //executes the code as it is true.

    String recorder_txt=//my storage file path
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Recorder_txt);
    String recordedNames = originalHS.toString();
    System.out.print("Writing recordedAccessions "+recordedNames);
    //Debug: Display Writing recordedAccessions [Smith, Johnson, Bates]

    writer.println (recordedNames);

    HashSet <String> retrievedHS =new HashSet <String>();

    HashSet <String> returnedHS= retrieve(Recorder_txt)
```

//made in another class in my own code, see method code below
//method that parse the HashSet written from original HS by writer in Recorder_txt
// It opens the file, read the line [name1,name2,...], suppresses [], split the line, load //names in the HashSet

```
        retrievedHS=returnedHS
    //or retrievedHS.addAll(returnedHS) 

    if(retrievedHS.contains(name)){ System.out.print("true");} 
    else { System.out.print("false");} 
    //DOES NOT WORK; it always returns false
```

Comment: Can you post file content? and what at the end you want to get.

Comment: I was told my code was to complex so I suppressed the parts which are not useful for your understanding.
What it will do if good comparison of name and HashSet<String> content is not relevant to the question. I thus tried to make it clear so that it doesn't parasite your reading.
What is relevant is that retrievedHS can't compare correctly, while originalHS does dans returnedHS is the same as originalHS, as it is build using a similar method. 
The problem happens when I do retrievedHS=returnedHS or retrievedHS.addAll(returnedHS).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is still not compiling, and thus hard to understand.  I see two main potential causes of your problem:

1. You're testing against `originalHS` at the beginning, but that's not what you're writing to the file. You're writing `nameCollection`.
2. You split on `","`, and don't trim the results. So a set containing `"Smith"`, `"Johnson"`, `"Bates"` will be written as `[Smith, Johnson, Bates]`, and be read as a set containing `"Smith"`, `" Johnson"`, `" Bates"` (i.e. there will be a leading space before each name except the first one).

Comment: 1. Sorry, I edited my mistake, i tried to make the names more clear to you but forgot something.

2. You do mean that I am tearing my hair because when I use write(originalHS.toString()) to write in the file, it is adding spaces (such as [name1, name2] ) instead of writing [name1,name2] in it?? 
Well, I will be trying to trim this. Thanks a lot.

(As for giving not compiling code, I had to shorten it the most because it would not be readable to you.)

Maxim Shoustin : thanks for your answer. Actually yes, my file is filled with [Smith, Johnson, Bates]. So I guess JB Nizet is right.